# Using "advantageous to" with things instead of people

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

See the definition of "advantageous" [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advantageous). The definition of the word includes "you", and it gives impression that you cannot say **advantageous to *something***. In the examples "advantageous **to**" is used with people or group of people like this:
**advantageous to the company** or **advantageous to the team**

you can say something like **advantageous interest rates**, and I guess it means that certain interest rates are good for someone or group of people.

However, I wonder whether you can write something like "**advantageous *To* the economy**" or "**advantageous *To* the employment level**", and I need the opinion of a native English speaker or teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advantageous** = providing an advantage; furnishing convenience or opportunity; favorable; profitable; useful; beneficial ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/advantageous)).

In English, something can be **advantageous** to virtually anything, not just people.

> Consumerism = the concept that an ever-expanding consumption of goods
>   is **advantageous to the economy** ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consumerism)).
>
> Adopting 'resource appropriate' measures which allow the most
>   effective treatment for the greatest number of people will be
>   **advantageous to countries** ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26913318)).
>
> ...and these 2 projects have come from
>   discussion with the staff as to work which would be **advantageous to
>   the animals** ([University of Reading](http://www.reading.ac.uk/internal/urop2019/archive/2009/detail.aspx?id=145)).
>
> Aquaponic systems like the Mulders' do, of course, benefit the fish,
>   but are also **advantageous to the plants** and humans involved...([Permaculturenews.com](https://permaculturenews.org/2016/01/19/converting-a-swimming-pool-to-grow-fish/)).

In certain cases, it may be better to say **beneficial** than advantageous:

> The association strives to promote the development of skills and
>   knowledge **beneficial to employment and investment opportunities** in
>   the real estate field ([lsu.edu](https://www.lsu.edu/business/finance/reri/index.php)).

What is the difference between advantageus and beneficial?

**Advantageous to** means resulting in a *better opportunity.*

**Beneficial** is a broader term that means being *helpful.*